# How to locate the path of parent directory in gulp.dest()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, frontend

I'm new comer in Gulp, and i got stock when i try to output my files to their parent's path.

**My directories like this:**

```
app/page_a/less/a.less
app/page_a/css
```

**My goal is:**

```
app/page_a/less/a.less
app/page_a/css/a.css
```

---

Here's what i'm doing:

> I use ** because i want to match all of my page_* module.

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
    var files = ['./app/**/*.less'];
    return gulp.src(files, {
            base: '.' // Now the base url becomes where the *.less is.
        })
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

---

**My result:( which is obviously wrong :( )**

```
app/page_a/less/a.less
app/page_a/less/a.css
app/page_a/css
```

## So how can i output `*.css` into the corresponding `app/page_*/css` path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you specify in the `base` option to `gulp.src()` isn't relative to each respective `.less` file, but rather the current working directory. This is usually the directory your `Gulpfile.js` resides in.

What you actually want to do is alter the path for each resulting `.css` file after your `less()` plugin has run, so when the `.css` files are written to the directory specified by `gulp.dest()` the `/less/` part of the path has been replaced with `/css/`.

This is exactly what the [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) plugin is for:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src( './app/**/*.less') 
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(rename(function(file) {
       file.dirname = file.dirname.replace(/less$/, "css");
    }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/'));
});
```

Comment: This is terrific, dude. I read the docs [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) and got the point —— **dirname is the relative path from the base directory set by gulp.src to the filename** (so here is `/**/*.less`), then we just need to give gulp.dest() a relative base path, which is the parent directory of **dirname**. Anyway, many thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

With gulp.dest('.') you say 'here'
Try with:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('./app/page_a/css/'));
```

This should be work

Comment: This doesn't work. Soon's use of the `base` option is wrong and your solution breaks for several reasons, most importantly when there are `.less` files in different subfolders like `./app/page_b/less/b.less` or `./app/page_c/less/c.less`.